# Возможно ли в своем типе данных объявить поле-функцию, которая автоматически применяет в качестве параметра другое поле этого типа

Tags: haskell

Например, имеется следующий тип данных:

```
data AnalogImpuls = AnalogImpuls{ amplitude :: Float,
                                  fade_function :: Float -> Float -> Float
                                }
```

Существует ли возможность слелать поле `fade_function` `Float -> Float` вместо `Float -> Float -> Float` так, чтобы в качестве одного параметра автоматически применялось значение `amplitude`? Что-то вроде

```
fade_function x = amplitude this + x
```

, где `this` это как текущий объект из ООП языков.

Я новичок в Хаскелле, так что прошу сильно не бить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, только писать придётся в стиле Python:

```
data AnalogImpuls = AnalogImpuls{ amplitude :: Float }
fade_function :: AnalogImpuls -> Float -> Float
fade_function self x = amplitude(self) + x
```

fade_function при этом как элемент структуры включать не надо, если он не должен специально задаваться для каждого её экземпляра.

Вызывать тоже придётся либо в стиле:

```
impuls `fade_function` value
```

Либо определять операцию обращения к элементам и методам структур `~>`:

```
object ~> method = method object
```

и вызывать

```
impuls~>fade_function value
```

Тогда и fade_function можно переписать в виде:

```
fade_function self x = self~>amplitude + x
```

Comment: Тут функция использовалась как член структуры для достижения полиморфизма, чтобы можно было разным сигналам установить разные функции, но сам вызов осуществлялся бы одинаково для всех

Comment: если весь перечень типов известен заранее, то можно сделать это через "сложение типов": `data Impuls = AudioImpulse {...} | ElectricImpulse {...}` и описать функцию для каждого случая. Если нет, то классы и, если надо объекты разного типа укладывать в один список/вектор/ассоциативный массив, то ещё и экзистенциальные типы.